# Lazy loading 3rd party component in loaded page (Ionic)

Tags: ionic-framework, lazy-loading, ionic3

The app working when i run  ionic cordova run android --device  but gives error when i try  ionic cordova run android --prod --release

I am trying use ng2-qrcode into my lazy loaded page

> Error: Unexpected value 'QRCodeComponent in
>   D:/qrstore/node_modules/ng2-qrcode/dist/ng2-qrcode.d.ts' declared by
>   the module 'ItemDetailPageModule in
>       D:/qrstore/src/pages/item-detail/item-detail.module.ts'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
>           at Error (native)
>           at syntaxError (D:\qrstore\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
>           at D:\qrstore\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15625:40
>           at Array.forEach (native)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (D:\qrstore\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15607:54)
>           at addNgModule (D:\qrstore\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24403:58)
>           at D:\qrstore\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24414:14
>           at Array.forEach (native)
>           at _createNgModules (D:\qrstore\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24413:26)
>           at analyzeNgModules (D:\qrstore\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24288:14)

ionic info

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.3
Node              : v6.9.4
npm               : 3.10.8
OS                : Windows 10
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

item detail module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ItemDetailPage } from './item-detail';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';

//native
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
import { SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

//providers
import { ItemsProvider, LabelsProvider, SQLiteDatabaseProvider } from '../../providers/providers';

//components
import { ItemCreatePage } from '../item-create/item-create';
import { QRCodeComponent } from 'ng2-qrcode'

//directive
import { AbsoluteDragDirective } from '../../directives/absolute-drag/absolute-drag';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ItemDetailPage,
    QRCodeComponent,
    AbsoluteDragDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ItemDetailPage),
    HttpModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ItemDetailPage
  ],
  entryComponents: []
  ,
  providers:[
    ItemsProvider,
    SQLite,
    SQLiteDatabaseProvider,
     File,
    FilePath
  ]
})
export class ItemDetailPageModule {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng2-qrcode` is no longer maintained and does not work with the AoT compiler of angular (which is used when you build your app with `--prod`). But there is a drop in replacement which is built for usage in Ionic3/Angular4+ projects which use the AoT compiler: [angularx-qrcode](https://github.com/Cordobo/angularx-qrcode). It is based on the same library and provides the same API.

Add it as follows:

```
npm install angularx-qrcode --save
```

And to use it import it in your `NgModule`:

```
import { QRCodeModule } from 'angularx-qrcode';
```

And then add it to the `imports` array:

```
imports: [
  QRCodeModule
],
```

Comment: Good info +1. One question: Is that mean can't we use any Angular component which doesn't develop by using `Angular 4` and above? In other words can't we use any `Angular 2` components with latest `Ionic 3` with `AOT`?

Comment: Thanks Sam! The component itself is no problem, if you copy paste it in your own project it should work just fine. The problem is how the library was published, to make your Angular2 library work with ngc (the angular compiler, which is ran ahead of time in prod mode) a few modifications have to be made (e.g. additionally to the *.d.ts files, *.metadata.json files are needed). You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/getting-your-angular-2-library-ready-for-aot-90d1347bcad). So most components should work with Angular4/Ionic3 but not this one because its unmaintained.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [angularx-qrcode](https://github.com/Cordobo/angularx-qrcode) mentioned above.

For those coming here and using the angularx-qrcode-package, I prepared a working angular-app for angular5/6 to have an easier start:

https://github.com/Cordobo/angularx-qrcode-sample-app

master-branch: latest angular, at the time of posting angular6
angular5-branch: you guessed it, is for angular5

HTH